# EFlow-Share brings rpc error " Did not find any matching sharedfolders!"

Tags: azure-iot-edge

in windows server 2022 have a running Eflow-Installation.
Want to add shared folders
Add-EflowVmSharedFolder -sharedFoldersJsonPath "D:\Shared\EFLOW-Shared\sharedFolders.json"
gives:
Creating storage sharedfolders under root (D:\Shared\EFLOW-Shared)

Did not find any matching sharedfolders!
Did not find any matching sharedfolders!

one yaml file is created in Eflow folder

Sharedfolders structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV817.png)

set all folder starting with Folder D:\Shared in properties to "shared" and access to "everyone R/W"

Content of json:

```
[
  {
    "sharedFolderRoot": "d:SharedEFLOW-Shared",
    "sharedFolders": [
      {
        "hostFolderPath": "cronicle",
        "readOnly": false,
        "targetFolderOnGuest": "/tmp/host-cronicle"
      },
      {
        "hostFolderPath": "RWAccess",
        "readOnly": false,
        "targetFolderOnGuest": "/tmp/host-rwaccess"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

created Folder regarding description:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-share-windows-folder-to-vm?view=iotedge-1.4

added property shared to everyone with R/W

Expecteds command to run command
Add-EflowVmSharedFolder -sharedFoldersJsonPath "D:\shared\EFLOW-Shared\sharedFolders.json"
successfull and sharing in VM granted.

Comment: Make to download the  [Azure iotedge-eflow](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-eflow/releases/)

Comment: will give a sample example to share with  add shared folders                                              ```Add-EflowVmSharedFolder```

Answer (score 0):

- Install EFLOW,virtiofs and Create a [PowerShell  Azure IoT Edge for Linux on WindowsEFLOW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/reference-iot-edge-for-linux-on-windows-functions?view=iotedge-1.4).

[image]

```
$msiPath = $([io.Path]::Combine($env:TEMP, 'AzureIoTEdge.msi'))
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Invoke-WebRequest "https://aka.ms/AzEFLOWMSI_1_4_LTS_X64" -OutFile $msiPath
```

```
Start-Process -Wait msiexec -ArgumentList "/i","$([io.Path]::Combine($env:TEMP, 'AzureIoTEdge.msi'))","/qn"
```

[image]

[image]

- [Share a Windows folder with Azure IoT Edge for Linux on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-share-windows-folder-to-vm?view=iotedge-1.4)
- Add the [sharedFolders.json](https://i.imgur.com/ZHlptUN.png)

```
Add-EflowVmSharedFolder -sharedFoldersJsonPath "C:\Shared\EFLOW-Shared\sharedFolders.json"
```

[image]

- `Connect-EflowVm` will connect to EflowVm
- [Cat command in Linux](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cat-command-in-linux-with-examples/)

```
sudo su
cd /tmp/host-read-access
cat Hello-World.txt
```

[image]

- With `/tmp/host-cronicle` and `/tmp/host-rwaccess`

[image]